# Permissions in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I was wondering if there is any specific command or some way to know the permissions that each file has in a directory. If someone knows and can help me, it would be very good.
Thank you.

Comment: So you want `ls -l`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/152001/how-can-i-get-octal-file-permissions-from-command-line if OP wants to use it programmatically, or `ls -l` if you just want to look at them.

Comment: @AdriaSambolaFarran: How about `stat FILENAME`?